# How can i replace the strings which I got from an array in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to replace the strings with other strings. How can I replace? Below code only changing the first message of if condition. I need to change all messages which I need.

Below changes only reflect for the My bag contains books.", "All the bag have balls". Other if's are not working. (i.e) first if only works and others are not.

Code:

```
renderMessages() {
  if (message.length > 2) {
     return (<Text>Available all sports items</Text>
  } else {
    return (
      this.state.validation.messages.map((msg) => {
        if (msg.indexOf('My bag contains books' > -1)) {
          let messagess = msg.replace("My bag contains books.", "All the bag have balls")
          return <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: 'red', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 0 }}>{messagess}</Text>
        }
        if (msg.indexOf('My badminton bat' > -1)) {
          let messagess = msg.replace("My badminton bat", "Our basket balls")
          return <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: 'red', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 0 }}>{messagess}</Text>
        }
        if (msg.indexOf('I have ball point pen' > -1)) {
          let messagess = msg.replace("I have ball point pen", "My pencils are in my bag")
          return <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: 'red', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 0 }}>{messagess}</Text>
        } else {
          return (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: 'red', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 0 }}>
              {msg}
            </Text>
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs in your code (as originally posted):

1. The parenthesis are misplaced in *all* of your match conditions:

   ```
   if (msg.indexOf('My bag contains books' > 0))
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   if (msg.indexOf('My bag contains books') > 0)
   ```
2. You have an "off-by-one" logic flaw in those same match conditions. 
   It should be

   ```
   if (msg.indexOf('My bag contains books') > -1)
   ```

   because the string indexes in Javascript, just like array indexes,
   start at 0. String.indexOf returns `-1` if there is no match.
   `> 0` would only make sense if you wanted to ignore matches at the
   beginning of the string.

Comment: Yes, it is -1. I have edited my code in my question. After changing to -1 the first message only gets changed and other messages are not changed.

Comment: OK, I found your other bug. I'll update my answer with my find, but only after you make two promises: In the future (1) run your code in a debugger and step through it to isolate where the logic is going wrong and uncover bugs, and (2) in future StackOverflow questions post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Code that runs and reproduces the flaw. Otherwise you're wasting other people's time going back and forth with you to fill in the blanks and also you are making other people do your work for you. Deal?

Comment: I will update all the reproducible code going forward. But I am not making you to do my works. This is one of my clarification. If you can share your idea.

Comment: @sejn Here you go.